# Can someone explain my Windows/SQL Server memory usage

Tags: sql-server, windows, sql-server-2005, memory, 64-bit

I'm running Windows Server 2003 x64 with 8GB RAM and SQL Server 2005 64 bit. I have SQL set to use loads of memory, but the SQL process only ever takes under 100 MB RAM. Is this normal? It is accessing data with indexes many GBs in size.

Moreover, no process is taking over 100MB, yet there is only a minimal (<100MB) amount ofree memory.

Could some kind person explain to me where the memory is being used and if the SQL memory usage is normal?

Memory usage:
http://img129.imageshack.us/img129/8624/02042009210608.png

SQL Server memory settings:

http://img10.imageshack.us/img10/8964/02042009210845.png

Memory details:

http://img228.imageshack.us/img228/3830/02042009210917.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value displayed is not the actual amount of used memory. [Mark Russinovich](http://blogs.technet.com/markrussinovich/) deals with memory managment issues on Windows in some posts in his blog. Have a look at [Pushing the Limits of Windows: Physical Memory](http://blogs.technet.com/markrussinovich/archive/2008/07/21/3092070.aspx) and [Pushing the Limits of Windows: Virtual Memory](http://blogs.technet.com/markrussinovich/archive/2008/11/17/3155406.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I recommend Process Explorer (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) as a better way to gauge how much memory a process is using. Right click on the header and choose "Select Columns" and then the "Process Memory" tab and finally check the "Private Bytes" and "Private Bytes History" options.

As far as your SQL memory configuration, I recommend setting the minimum to whatever you *know* you will never need on the machine for other tasks, and the maximum to what pushes you to filling the physical memory (counting other processes), but no farther.

Comment: Iirc Process Explorer won't expose memory allocated via AWE.

Comment: Hmmm, that might have been true. AWE is no longer supported in the newer SQL server and only mattered to 32 bit OS, so that shouldn't be an issue for someone coming back to this. (Also, if you are using AWE, you should know what you are doing as it is a manual allocation.)

Comment: "Locked Pages in Memory" in SQL Server 64-bit uses the Windows AWE API to do memory allocations. This affects SQL Server x64 and memory allocated this way does not appear in Process Explorer.

Comment: Supplementary note. Locked Pages in Memory is on *by default* for Local System account. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2007/10/18/do-i-have-to-assign-the-lock-privilege-for-local-system.aspx. So on any SQL Server x64 running under Local System or any account given Lock Pages privileges, memory is allocated using AWE API and will not appear in Process Explorer.

Answer (score 2):

The memory usage is normal for those settings, and although you don't see it in the task manager, it's the SQL Server that is using the memory.

However, as you see the total memory usage is more than there is physical memory, which is bad for the server's performance. You should *not* set the memory limit for the database server to more than you have physical memory. The database server uses the memory to cache data and results, and if it has to swap the cache from disk there is no gain in having it.

Comment: I came across this post by an MVP, http://sql-server-performance.com/Community/forums/p/23311/132285.aspx (last post on page) advising to leave the memory as dynamic. Is he wrong?

Comment: Memory should be left as dynamic, but the maximum amount of memory that SQL can use should be set to 1-2 Gigs less than the physical memory installed.

Answer (score 1):

Discovered this question when searching for SQL Server memory not being shown in Process Explorer. The reason for this is on SQL Server 32-bit and 64-bit, memory allocation can be configured to use the AWE API.

The prerequisite for this is *Lock Pages in Memory* has to be configured for the account that the SQL Server process runs under. This applies for both 32-bit and 64-bit. This is done via *Group Policy Editor* (gpedit.msc) then navigating to *Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Local Policies -> User Rights Assignment* then adding the appropriate account to the *Lock pages in memory* policy setting.

Local System by default already has this (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2007/10/18/do-i-have-to-assign-the-lock-privilege-for-local-system.aspx).

For SQL Server 32-bit 2005 - 2008R2, you then need to enable AWE in Memory Options via *Use AWE to allocate memory*. SQL Server 2012 32-bit and higher no longer has this option.

For SQL Server 64-bit, having *Lock Pages in Memory* will use AWE to allocate memory.

In order to see these AWE memory allocations, you can use a memory mapper tool such as *Sysinternals RAMMap* http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/sysinternals/ff700229.aspx.

You can determine if your SQL Server is using Locked Pages via this:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO

EXEC xp_cmdshell 'whoami /priv'
GO

EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 0
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

and you should see *SeLockMemoryPrivilege* is Enabled.

For SQL Server 32-bit, you can then confirm AWE is enabled via (don't need this check for 64-bit):

```
EXEC sp_configure 'awe enabled'
GO
```

and the run_value should be 1.

If it turns out your server is not using AWE allocated memory, using Sysinternals Process Explorer (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) as per Godeke's post is the nicer way to go - better interface and easier to understand/use.

Answer (score 0):

> By default, SQL Server dynamically grows and shrinks the size of its
>   buffer pool (cache) depending on the physical memory load reported by
>   the operating system. As long as enough memory is available to prevent
>   paging (between 4 - 10 MB), the SQL Server buffer pool will continue
>   to grow. As other processes on the same computer as SQL Server
>   allocate memory, the SQL Server buffer manager will release memory as
>   needed. SQL Server can free and acquire several megabytes of memory
>   each second, allowing it to quickly adjust to memory allocation
>   changes.

source: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321363